# How to cast a UI Element to a View Model

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a View Model

```
public class TreeViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<NodeViewModel> Items { get; set; }
}

public class NodeViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<NodeViewModel> Children { get; set; }
}
```

And Display a TreeView with HierarchicalDataTemplate with it.

Now im Trying to get the NodeViewModel Element when someone clicks on the TreeViewItem. The TreeViewItem consists of a Grid with some other Controls in it actually.

```
    private NodeViewModel GetNearestContainer(UIElement element)
    {
        // Walk up the element tree to the nearest tree view item.
        UIElement UIContainer;
        NodeViewModel NVContainer;

        UIContainer = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element) as UIElement;

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                NVContainer = UIContainer as ????;
                break;
            }
            catch Exception
            {
                UIContainer = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(UIContainer) as UIElement;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

How do I get the GetNearestContainer to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get underlying source by accessing **`DataContext`** property but it's declared on FrameworkElement so you can directly get it from TreeViewItem object.

Also, it seems you want to get TreeViewItem recursively, so first add this utility method to get you TreeViewItem:

```
private static Parent FindParent<Parent>(DependencyObject child)
    where Parent : DependencyObject
{
    DependencyObject parentObject = child;
    parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parentObject);

    //check if the parent matches the type we're looking for
    if (parentObject is Parent || parentObject == null)
    {
        return parentObject as Parent;
    }
    else
    {
        //use recursion to proceed with next level
        return FindParent<Parent>(parentObject);
    }
}
```

and then change your method to this:

```
private NodeViewModel GetNearestContainer(UIElement element)
{
    // Walk up the element tree to the nearest tree view item.
    TreeViewItem UIContainer = FindParent<TreeViewItem>(element);
    NodeViewModel NVContainer = null;

    if (UIContainer != null)
    {
        NVContainer = UIContainer.DataContext as NodeViewModel;
    }
    return NVContainer;
}
```